# Bonita Form bordering specific rows

Tags: bonita

I have gone through many sites but couldn't find any answer.

The thing is i am generating a bonita form using the variables, the form consists of automatically generated rows with the fields of variables.

Well, basically my issue is to border only some of those specific generated rows.

The rows are dynamically generated so i couldn't apply css for the internal rows but i can apply css for the div's such as "bonita_form_container" as such.

Can anyone help me out in this regard.

Comment: Which version of BonitaBPM are you using? what form element are you using? Is there any custom code on the form?

Comment: The BonitaBPM version is 6.2.1, well basically i am using textboxes and text areas in the form, the form is generated by the traditional drag and drop method only there is no custom code written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the widgets in a bonitasoft form have no borders. You need to change the css / less files of the bonitasoft theme that is used. In the commercial editions that can be done by creating a new look 'n' feel, as explained in this article:

http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/creating-new-look-feel

However, this functionality is not available in the community edition. In the community edition it can be done, you have to edit the files under:

```
<BONITA_HOME>\client\tenants\1\work\forms\<Processname>\<ProcesInstanceId>\resources\application\css\bonita_form_default.css
```

You need to edit the

```
.bonita_table_container
```

class and set some border properties with css.

Be carefull, a new processinstance (with a new id and directory) will be generated every time you redeploy.